# Android: Cannot set init listView for using in custom modal

Tags: android, listview, modal-dialog

in activity i have following:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_meal_country);
```

ListView xml is not part of the actual visible activity.

ListView Should be displayed in the custom modal window:

But if i try to check

```
if(lv == null)
                Logger.e("LV IS NULL");
```

I get always null result.

So i cannot set custom adapter to listView.

How can i avoid to ger listView null when Layout which is containing listVIew is not initialized?

Layout of the modal window:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="TEST1" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="TEST"/>

    <!-- LIST VIEW -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_meal_country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to append Lv after append content to modal, but result is still same:

```
boolean wrapInScrollView = true;
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx)
                    .title("TEST")
                    .customView(R.layout.custom_modal_list, wrapInScrollView)
                    .show();

            ListView lv = (ListView)  ctx.findViewById(R.id.list_view_meal_country);
            if(lv == null)
                Logger.e("LV IS NULL");
```

How can i solve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your custom view with [`getCustomView()`](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#later-access), then you can use findViewById to access the listview

```
MaterialDialog.Builder dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(ctx)
                    .title("TEST")
                    .customView(R.layout.custom_modal_list, wrapInScrollView)
                    .show();

dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.list_view_meal_country);
```